# Comparing the marginal effects of glm output to polr output

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model-comparison, quasi-likelihood, ordered-probit

I have a dependent variable that is technically ordinal, so I ran a ordered probit model (`polr`).
However, an ordered probit model does not produce any residuals which I needed ([post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518535/how-to-get-residuals-from-an-ordinal-logit-probit-and-which-ones-to-get)). I thought maybe I can compare a couple of models (that do produce residuals) and see to what extent the estimate of my variable of interest differs (especially since I read that an ordinal probit is essentially a special case of a glm ([answer by @suncoolsu](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7720/how-to-understand-output-from-rs-polr-function-ordered-logistic-regression))).

## EDIT:

**Crime is in this example a dummy variable (I have recoded it to a dummy)**

I decided to, in addition to an ordered probit model, also run GLM from the quasipoisson family.
My output (only showing the variable of interest) looks as follows:

```
polr_1st <- polr(polr_form_1st, Hess=TRUE, method="probit", data=full) ;summary(polr_1st)

                                    Value Std. Error   t value
Crime                          0.45799229  0.0253234  18.08573


glm_1st <- glm(glm_form_1st, family="quasipoisson", data=full); summary(glm_1st)

                                Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   -0.2140713  0.0875054  -2.446             0.014438 *  
Crime                          0.3524041  0.0221681  15.897 < 0.0000000000000002 **
```

So the estimates are quite a bit different, but I thought lets look at the `margins` ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html)).

```
polr_1st_margins <- summary(margins(polr_1st, variables = "Crime")) 

factor     AME     SE        z      p   lower   upper
  Crime -0.1546 0.0084 -18.3506 0.0000 -0.1712 -0.1381

summary(margins(glm_1st, variables = "Crime"))

factor    AME     SE       z      p  lower  upper
Crime 0.3302 0.0209 15.7771 0.0000 0.2892 0.3712
```

To my surprise, the marginal effect of the bigger (`polr`) coefficient is negative (see also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520009/the-interpretation-of-a-positive-glm-coefficient-with-a-negative-marginal-effec)).

Does this mean that these models are in the end so different that I just cannot compare them? If yes, is there any model that comes close to `polr` which produces residuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. It seems that the `margins` package, in the `polr` example above, only shows the Average Marginal Effect (AME) for the first category. When running the `margins` command in Stata, the reason for the negative AME becomes clear (interpretation is very well explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9kvqeLFF8U)).

The marginal effects should be interpreted as follows: If crime dummy variable equals one, the percentage chance that the observation is in the first category, indeed goes down by about 15%. But looking at the other categories, their cumulative chance, increases by 15%.

The chance that an observation is in the second category increases by 1.45%, the chance that an observation is in the third category increases by just under 4% and finally the chance that an observation is in the fourth category increases by just under 9.55%, which together makes 15%.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
               |            Delta-method
               |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+------------------------------------------------
Crime@_predict |
   (1 vs 0) 1  |  -.1496894   .0083357      -.166027   -.1333517
   (1 vs 0) 2  |   .0145286   .0007616      .0130359    .0160214
   (1 vs 0) 3  |    .039654   .0021988      .0353445    .0439636
   (1 vs 0) 4  |   .0955067   .0060038      .0837395    .1072739
----------------------------------------------------------------
```