# I replicated ordered probit output (using a Stata dataset) with four R packages, compared it to Stata, unable to even come close to the Stata output

Tags: r, stata, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

I was trying to reverse engineer the values of an unclear parameter by comparing `R` outcomes to `Stata` outcomes for an ordinal probit model ([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521808/generalised-residuals-estimated-value-of-the-density-at-that-point-for-observa)). To my surprise I could not replicate the outcome (fake data set with 2000 observations). To be sure, I decided to replicate the ordinal probit models with a `Stata` dataset. As the results (below) show, the differences in output were not a coincidence. **I provided all data and code for both Stata and R below**
Although I did not expect the results to be completely identical, they are off by quite some margin.

Because of this, I have two questions:

1. Is there an `R` package that is able to replicate the `Stata` results, so that I can reverse engineer the values that I am looking for?
2. Can anyone shed any sort of light on these differences. What is it about these models that makes these differences so large and what does that say about any result from an ordinal model?

References: https://www.stata.com/manuals14/roprobit.pdf

**NOTE: Everyone, please feel encouraged to check if there are any mistakes in my code that might explain the differences**

## Replication

In Stata, with `oprobit`:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/fullauto

oprobit rep77 foreign length mpg

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -89.895098  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -78.106316  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -78.020086  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -78.020025  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -78.020025  

Ordered probit regression                       Number of obs     =         66
                                                LR chi2(3)        =      23.75
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -78.020025                     Pseudo R2         =     0.1321

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       rep77 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |   1.704861   .4246796     4.01   0.000     .8725037    2.537217
      length |   .0468675    .012648     3.71   0.000      .022078    .0716571
         mpg |   .1304559   .0378628     3.45   0.001     .0562463    .2046656
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       /cut1 |    10.1589   3.076754                      4.128577    16.18923
       /cut2 |   11.21003   3.107527                      5.119389    17.30067
       /cut3 |   12.54561   3.155233                      6.361467    18.72975
       /cut4 |   13.98059   3.218793                      7.671874    20.28931
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In `R`, with `polr` from the `MASS` package:

```
library(MASS)
polr  <- polr(as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, Hess=TRUE, data=fullauto);summary(polr)

Call:
polr(formula = as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, data = fullauto, 
    Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
        Value Std. Error t value
foreign 2.89680    0.79106   3.662
length  0.08283    0.02277   3.637
mpg     0.23077    0.07053   3.272

Intercepts:
    Value   Std. Error t value
1|2 17.9273  5.5637     3.2222
2|3 19.8649  5.6071     3.5428
3|4 22.1031  5.7188     3.8650
4|5 24.6919  5.9037     4.1825

Residual Deviance: 156.5014 
AIC: 170.5014
```

In `R`, with `vglm` from the `VGAM` package:

```
library(VGAM)
vglm <- vglm(as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, family=propodds, data=fullauto);summary(vglm)

Call:
vglm(formula = as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, family = propodds, 
    data = fullauto)

Coefficients: 
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept):1 -17.92738    5.47221  -3.276 0.001053 ** 
(Intercept):2 -19.86496    5.52892  -3.593 0.000327 ***
(Intercept):3 -22.10321    5.63780  -3.921 8.84e-05 ***
(Intercept):4 -24.69203    5.81757  -4.244 2.19e-05 ***
foreign         2.89684    0.75766   3.823 0.000132 ***
length          0.08283    0.02252   3.677 0.000236 ***
mpg             0.23076    0.06805   3.391 0.000696 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Names of linear predictors: logitlink(P[Y>=2]), logitlink(P[Y>=3]), logitlink(P[Y>=4]), logitlink(P[Y>=5])

Residual deviance: 156.5014 on 257 degrees of freedom

Log-likelihood: -78.2507 on 257 degrees of freedom

Number of Fisher scoring iterations: 6 

No Hauck-Donner effect found in any of the estimates


Exponentiated coefficients:
foreign    length       mpg 
18.116799  1.086354  1.259563
```

In `R`, with `clm` from the `ordinal` package:

```
clm <- clm(as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, data=fullauto)
summary(clm)

formula: as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg
data:    fullauto

link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter max.grad cond.H 
logit flexible  66   -78.25 170.50 6(0)  5.65e-10 8.9e+07

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
foreign  2.89681    0.79064   3.664 0.000248 ***
length   0.08283    0.02272   3.646 0.000267 ***
mpg      0.23077    0.07045   3.275 0.001055 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2   17.927      5.551   3.229
2|3   19.865      5.596   3.550
3|4   22.103      5.709   3.872
4|5   24.692      5.891   4.192
(8 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

In `R`, with `orm` from the `rms` package:

```
library(rms)
orm <- orm(as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, family=probit, data=fullauto)
dd <- datadist(fullauto)
options(datadist="dd")
summary(orm)

            Effects              Response : as.ordered(rep77) 

Factor  Low High   Diff. Effect  S.E.    Lower 0.95 Upper 0.95
foreign   0   1.00  1.00 1.70480 0.42468 0.87249    2.5372    
length  170 203.75 33.75 1.58180 0.42687 0.74512    2.4184    
mpg      18  24.75  6.75 0.88057 0.25557 0.37966    1.3815
```

## DATA for R

```
fullauto <- structure(list(make = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23), label = "Make", format.stata = "%8.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(AMC = 1, Audi = 2, BMW = 3, 
Buick = 4, Cad. = 5, Chev. = 6, Datsun = 7, Dodge = 8, Fiat = 9, 
Ford = 10, Honda = 11, Linc. = 12, Mazda = 13, Merc. = 14, Olds = 15, 
Peugeot = 16, Plym. = 17, Pont. = 18, Renault = 19, Subaru = 20, 
Toyota = 21, VW = 22, Volvo = 23)), model = structure(c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 5000, 320, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 200, 210, 510, 810, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 98, 604, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 260), label = "Model", format.stata = "%8.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Concord = 1, Pacer = 2, Spirit = 3, 
Fox = 4, Century = 5, Electra = 6, LeSabre = 7, Opel = 8, Regal = 9, 
Riviera = 10, Skylark = 11, Deville = 12, Eldrado = 13, Seville = 14, 
Chevette = 15, Impala = 16, Malibu = 17, MCarlo = 18, Monza = 19, 
Nova = 20, Colt = 21, Diplomat = 22, Magnum = 23, StRegis = 24, 
Strada = 25, Fiesta = 26, Mustang = 27, Accord = 28, Civic = 29, 
Cntntl = 30, `Mark V` = 31, Vrsills = 32, GLC = 33, Bobcat = 34, 
Cougar = 35, `XR-7` = 36, Marquis = 37, Monarch = 38, Zephyr = 39, 
Cutlass = 40, CutlSupr = 41, `Delta 88` = 42, Omega = 43, Starfire = 44, 
Toronado = 45, Arrow = 46, Champ = 47, Horizon = 48, Sapporo = 49, 
Volare = 50, Catalina = 51, Firebird = 52, GranPrix = 53, `Le Mans` = 54, 
Phoenix = 55, Sunbird = 56, `Le Car` = 57, Subaru = 58, Celica = 59, 
Corolla = 60, Corona = 61, Rabbit = 62, Diesel = 63, Scirocco = 64, 
Dasher = 65)), price = structure(c(4099, 4749, 3799, 6295, 9690, 
9735, 4816, 7827, 5788, 4453, 5189, 10372, 4082, 11385, 14500, 
15906, 3299, 5705, 4504, 5104, 3667, 3955, 6229, 4589, 5079, 
8129, 3984, 4010, 5886, 6342, 4296, 4389, 4187, 5799, 4499, 11497, 
13594, 13466, 3995, 3829, 5379, 6303, 6165, 4516, 3291, 4733, 
5172, 4890, 4181, 4195, 10371, 8814, 12990, 4647, 4425, 4482, 
6486, 4060, 5798, 4934, 5222, 4723, 4424, 4172, 3895, 3798, 5899, 
3748, 5719, 4697, 5397, 6850, 7140, 11995), label = "Price", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    mpg = structure(c(22, 17, 22, 23, 17, 25, 20, 15, 18, 26, 
    20, 16, 19, 14, 14, 21, 29, 16, 22, 22, 24, 19, 23, 35, 24, 
    21, 30, 18, 16, 17, 21, 28, 21, 25, 28, 12, 12, 14, 30, 22, 
    14, 14, 15, 18, 20, 19, 19, 18, 19, 24, 16, 21, 14, 38, 34, 
    25, 26, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 24, 26, 35, 18, 31, 18, 25, 
    41, 25, 23, 17), label = "Mileage (mpg)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    rep78 = structure(c(3, 3, NA, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 
    3, 4, NA, 3, 5, 3, NA, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5), label = "Repair Record 1978", format.stata = "%9.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Poor = 1, Fair = 2, Average = 3, 
    Good = 4, Excellent = 5)), rep77 = structure(c(2, 1, NA, 
    3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, NA, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 2, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, 2, 4, 
    2, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), label = "Repair Record 1977", format.stata = "%9.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Poor = 1, Fair = 2, Average = 3, 
    Good = 4, Excellent = 5)), hdroom = structure(c(2.5, 3, 3, 
    2.5, 3, 2.5, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 4, 
    3.5, 2, 2, 3.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 4, 4, 4.5, 2.5, 1.5, 
    2, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 
    2, 4, 4.5, 2, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 4, 1.5, 5, 4, 1.5, 2, 
    3.5, 3.5, 2, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2.5, 2.5), label = "Headroom (in.)", format.stata = "%6.1f"), 
    rseat = structure(c(27.5, 25.5, 18.5, 28, 27, 26, 29, 31.5, 
    30.5, 24, 28.5, 30, 27, 31.5, 30, 30, 26, 29.5, 28.5, 28.5, 
    25, 27, 21, 23.5, 22, 27, 24, 29, 29, 28, 26.5, 26, 23, 25.5, 
    23.5, 30.5, 28.5, 27, 25.5, 25.5, 29.5, 25, 30.5, 27, 29, 
    28, 28, 29, 27, 25.5, 30, 31.5, 30.5, 21.5, 23, 25, 22, 31, 
    29, 23.5, 28.5, 28, 27, 25, 23, 25.5, 22, 24.5, 23, 25.5, 
    25.5, 23.5, 37.5, 29.5), label = "Rear Seat (in.)", format.stata = "%6.1f"), 
    trunk = structure(c(11, 11, 12, 11, 15, 12, 16, 20, 21, 10, 
    16, 17, 13, 20, 16, 13, 9, 20, 17, 16, 7, 13, 6, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 17, 17, 21, 16, 9, 10, 10, 5, 22, 18, 15, 11, 9, 16, 16, 
    23, 15, 17, 16, 16, 20, 14, 10, 17, 20, 14, 11, 11, 17, 8, 
    16, 20, 7, 16, 17, 13, 7, 10, 11, 14, 9, 11, 15, 15, 16, 
    12, 14), label = "Trunk space (cu. ft.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    weight = structure(c(2930, 3350, 2640, 2070, 2830, 2650, 
    3250, 4080, 3670, 2230, 3280, 3880, 3400, 4330, 3900, 4290, 
    2110, 3690, 3180, 3220, 2750, 3430, 2370, 2020, 2280, 2750, 
    2120, 3600, 3600, 3740, 2130, 1800, 2650, 2240, 1760, 4840, 
    4720, 3830, 1980, 2580, 4060, 4130, 3720, 3370, 2830, 3300, 
    3310, 3690, 3370, 2730, 4030, 4060, 3420, 3260, 1800, 2200, 
    2520, 3330, 3700, 3470, 3210, 3200, 3420, 2690, 1830, 2050, 
    2410, 2200, 2670, 1930, 2040, 1990, 2160, 3170), label = "Weight (lbs.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    length = structure(c(186, 173, 168, 174, 189, 177, 196, 222, 
    218, 170, 200, 207, 200, 221, 204, 204, 163, 212, 193, 200, 
    179, 197, 170, 165, 170, 184, 163, 206, 206, 220, 161, 147, 
    179, 172, 149, 233, 230, 201, 154, 169, 221, 217, 212, 198, 
    195, 198, 198, 218, 200, 180, 206, 220, 192, 170, 157, 165, 
    182, 201, 214, 198, 201, 199, 203, 179, 142, 164, 174, 165, 
    175, 155, 155, 156, 172, 193), label = "Length (in.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    turn = structure(c(40, 40, 35, 36, 37, 34, 40, 43, 43, 34, 
    42, 43, 42, 44, 43, 45, 34, 43, 31, 41, 40, 43, 35, 32, 34, 
    38, 35, 46, 46, 46, 36, 33, 43, 36, 34, 51, 48, 41, 33, 39, 
    48, 45, 44, 41, 43, 42, 42, 42, 43, 40, 43, 43, 38, 37, 37, 
    36, 38, 44, 42, 42, 45, 40, 43, 41, 34, 36, 36, 35, 36, 35, 
    35, 36, 36, 37), label = "Turn Circle (ft.) ", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    displ = structure(c(121, 258, 121, 97, 131, 121, 196, 350, 
    231, 304, 196, 231, 231, 425, 350, 350, 231, 250, 200, 200, 
    151, 250, 119, 85, 119, 146, 98, 318, 318, 225, 105, 98, 
    140, 107, 91, 400, 400, 302, 86, 140, 302, 302, 302, 250, 
    140, 231, 231, 231, 231, 151, 350, 350, 163, 156, 86, 105, 
    119, 225, 231, 231, 231, 231, 231, 151, 79, 97, 134, 97, 
    134, 89, 90, 97, 97, 163), label = "Displacement (cu. in.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    gratio = structure(c(3.57999992370605, 2.52999997138977, 
    3.07999992370605, 3.70000004768372, 3.20000004768372, 3.64000010490417, 
    2.9300000667572, 2.41000008583069, 2.73000001907349, 2.86999988555908, 
    2.9300000667572, 2.9300000667572, 3.07999992370605, 2.27999997138977, 
    2.19000005722046, 2.24000000953674, 2.9300000667572, 2.55999994277954, 
    2.73000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 2.55999994277954, 
    3.89000010490417, 3.70000004768372, 3.53999996185303, 3.54999995231628, 
    3.53999996185303, 2.47000002861023, 2.47000002861023, 2.94000005722046, 
    3.36999988555908, 3.15000009536743, 3.07999992370605, 3.04999995231628, 
    3.29999995231628, 2.47000002861023, 2.47000002861023, 2.47000002861023, 
    3.73000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 2.75, 2.75, 2.25999999046326, 
    2.4300000667572, 3.07999992370605, 2.9300000667572, 2.9300000667572, 
    2.73000001907349, 3.07999992370605, 2.73000001907349, 2.41000008583069, 
    2.41000008583069, 3.57999992370605, 3.04999995231628, 2.97000002861023, 
    3.36999988555908, 3.53999996185303, 3.23000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 
    3.07999992370605, 2.9300000667572, 2.9300000667572, 3.07999992370605, 
    2.73000001907349, 3.72000002861023, 3.80999994277954, 3.05999994277954, 
    3.21000003814697, 3.04999995231628, 3.77999997138977, 3.77999997138977, 
    3.77999997138977, 3.74000000953674, 2.98000001907349), label = "Gear Ratio", format.stata = "%6.2f"), 
    order = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
    28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
    43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 46, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
    58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 
    73, 74), label = "Original order", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    foreign = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "Foreign", format.stata = "%8.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Domestic = 0, Foreign = 1
    )), wgtd = structure(c(2930, 3350, 2640, NA, NA, NA, 3250, 
    4080, 3670, 2230, 3280, 3880, 3400, 4330, 3900, 4290, 2110, 
    3690, 3180, 3220, 2750, 3430, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2120, 3600, 
    3600, 3740, NA, 1800, 2650, NA, NA, 4840, 4720, 3830, NA, 
    2580, 4060, 4130, 3720, 3370, 2830, 3300, 3310, 3690, 3370, 
    2730, 4030, 4060, NA, 3260, 1800, 2200, 2520, 3330, 3700, 
    3470, 3210, 3200, 3420, 2690, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), format.stata = "%9.0g"), wgtf = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 2070, 2830, 2650, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2370, 2020, 2280, 2750, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2130, NA, NA, 2240, 1760, NA, NA, NA, 1980, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3420, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1830, 2050, 2410, 
    2200, 2670, 1930, 2040, 1990, 2160, 3170), format.stata = "%9.0g")), label = "Automobile Models", row.names = c(NA, 
-74L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't think polr(·) defaults to probit...try including the argument method="probit"

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Will update!

Comment: @GreggH That was it.. I cannot believe I missed that.. Thank you so much!

Comment: I guess that means I can delete the question.

Comment: I'd leave it up...other's may encounter a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Gregg H's suggestions, I will leave up this post (and put an answer, just to show that this post has a solution).

The problem was that in `polr`, (as well as `vglm` and `clm`), the probit method was not explicitly specified.

```
polr  <- polr(as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, method="probit", Hess=TRUE, 
data=fullauto);summary(polr)

Call:
polr(formula = as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, data = fullauto, 
    Hess = TRUE, method = "probit")

Coefficients:
          Value Std. Error t value
foreign 1.70386    0.42478   4.011
length  0.04681    0.01264   3.702
mpg     0.13032    0.03786   3.442

Intercepts:
    Value   Std. Error t value
1|2 10.1452  3.0762     3.2980
2|3 11.1963  3.1068     3.6038
3|4 12.5316  3.1544     3.9727
4|5 13.9663  3.2185     4.3394

Residual Deviance: 156.0401 
AIC: 170.0401 
(8 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Stata:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/fullauto

oprobit rep77 foreign length mpg

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -89.895098  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -78.106316  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -78.020086  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -78.020025  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -78.020025  

Ordered probit regression                       Number of obs     =         66
                                                LR chi2(3)        =      23.75
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -78.020025                     Pseudo R2         =     0.1321

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       rep77 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |   1.704861   .4246796     4.01   0.000     .8725037    2.537217
      length |   .0468675    .012648     3.71   0.000      .022078    .0716571
         mpg |   .1304559   .0378628     3.45   0.001     .0562463    .2046656
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       /cut1 |    10.1589   3.076754                      4.128577    16.18923
       /cut2 |   11.21003   3.107527                      5.119389    17.30067
       /cut3 |   12.54561   3.155233                      6.361467    18.72975
       /cut4 |   13.98059   3.218793                      7.671874    20.28931
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```